# Exact first order perturbation expansion of matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, perturbation-theory

Let $I$ be an $n\times n$ identity matrix, $B$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with all the elements tending to zero. If we can expression $det(I+B)= 1 + f(B) + o(f^2(B))$, as all the elements of $B$ go to zero, where $f(B)$ is the first order expansion term, what is the exact form of $f(B)$? I have been searching for the answer to this question for very long...I know there are some inequalities but I'd like to know the exact form of $f(B)$, if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact form is $f(B) = \mathrm{tr\ } B.$

Comment: ... except that the error is not $o((\text{tr}\; B)^2)$, or even $O(\text{tr}\; B))$.  There are, after all, matrices $B$ with trace $0$ such that $\det(I+B) \ne 1$.

Comment: Thank you both! Is there a general expression for the remainder term, or a higher order expansion?

Comment: @BillJ For a second order expansion, see https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208223